# ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlement"

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/Mightier.app/.

We didn't change any setting related to the associated domain. its stopped worked when i renewed my certs and profile.

Answer (score 0):

When are you getting this error?

From the error, It looks like you're using wildcard certificate (*) which is not allowed to release build on App store.